# Unable to like on Facebook - publish_actions missing - will publish_stream do?

Tags: android, facebook

Android Facebook app:

1. I have an android app which has custom like button.
2. When this button is hit, I am currently calling login to facebook with "publish_stream" permission.
3. Upon login, the access token is passed to the backend where we use graph api to like it for the user and accumulate all the like counts.
4. Effective 1 May 2015 - FB has blocked the api as "publish_actions" permission is missing.
5. The step to resolve seems like adding "publish_actions" to the application code and asking facebook to review the same.

My questions is that - 
If I do not change my code and want to support the applications already installed, and if we go to Facebook and submit for review. While submitting, add publish_actions on facebook developer. Will it work?
OR
the only way is to add permission and upgrade the app?

**Update**:

From the reply - it is clear that current app will not work as is.

There are 2 options which I see:

1. add publish_actions permission and go for review with facebook.
2. If I don't want to add this permission - I can add the facebook like button to my view using facebook sdk.
   [Link to add like is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button)
   However, not too sure what are the customization options on this button? 
   a. Can I override this view with my own image? 
   b. What are the options FB provides? [In the document here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LikeView) read about this: public void setLikeViewStyle(Style likeViewStyle) - but no pictorial depiction is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the app and ask for publish_actions. publish_streams was deprecated several years ago and finally removed end of April this year

Comment: Sure! thanks for the help. Our bad - we missed the update. But is there any other way possible, than upgrading the application - as the application is already installed in millions of devices? I mean can we request publish_actions in the status page at facebook developer and will it work with publish_stream? Did any one try that? Not able to connect with Facebook Developers too! Thanks

Comment: Oh I realize you are working @ Facebook - may be you can give me the right answer - is there any way we can avoid application upgrade?

Comment: No there is not. That why we told everyone more than a year ago that they need to upgrade there apps

Comment: So I see two Options - 1. by including permission of publish_actions. 2. by adding Facebook Like button view to my Android app and let Facebook handle it - reference: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button) For the option 2 - what are the customization options available for the button? Can I over-ride it with my own button? Or I have to use one of the styles mentioned here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LikeView) -- likeViewStyle Should be either LikeView.STANDARD, LikeView.BUTTON or LikeView.BOX_COUNT

Comment: updated my question to ask this better. Please check the update section